# Unable to call typescript function inside OpenLayers function

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I have a problem using OpenLayers with TypeScript in Angular.
I have a event listener for my ol map

```
  this.map.on('click', function (e) {
      let x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
      this.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
    });
```

x[0] and x[1] are my lat and lon values.
If I call the function addMarker I will receive the error when clicking on the map:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.addMarker is not a function
at Map.<anonymous> (map.component.ts:90)
at Map.push.../node_modules/ol/events/Target.js.Target.dispatchEvent (Target.js:113)
at Map.push.../node_modules/ol/PluggableMap.js.PluggableMap.handleMapBrowserEvent (PluggableMap.js:871)
at MapBrowserEventHandler.push.../node_modules/ol/events/Target.js.Target.dispatchEvent (Target.js:113)
at MapBrowserEventHandler.push.../node_modules/ol/MapBrowserEventHandler.js.MapBrowserEventHandler.emulateClick_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:97)
at MapBrowserEventHandler.push.../node_modules/ol/MapBrowserEventHandler.js.MapBrowserEventHandler.handlePointerUp_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js:148)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

This is my addMarker Method:

```
addMarker(lon, lat) {
  let marker = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point(transform([lon + 0.01, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
  });
  this.source.addFeature(marker);
}
```

I don`t know how to fix this problem or if there is a workaround.

I hope you can help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the syntax you are using.
Use this code in the `this.map`.
You can do two things.

1. Use arrow function(recommended).

```
this.map.on('click', (e) => {
    const x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
    this.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
});
```

2. Store `this` in variable and then use that variable.

```
const _that = this;
this.map.on('click', function(e) {
    const x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
    _that.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
});
```

The reason being, the scope of `this`. when you create a function like `function(){}` this refers to this function, but when you use `arrow` function the `this` will refer to `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the reference of 'this' to another variable before calling the method.

```
const self = this;
this.map.on('click', function (e) {
      let x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
      self.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
});
```

In the click event handler, the scope of this changes. Therefore, the addMarker was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself:
Change this:

```
 this.map.on('click', function (e) {
      let x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
      this.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
    });
```

To:

```
this.map.on('click', (e) => {
      let x = transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
      this.addMarker(x[0], x[1]);
    });
```